# expected expression, but it's already there?

Tags: c, cs50

1. Goal: To create a database for five Mcdonalds items, includes item name and ingredients, eventually, I want to compare a users food allergies with the database for Mcdonalds
2. Error message "expected expression" occurs on all items for all Mcdonalds[].ingredients

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cs50.h> 
//Fastfood restarunt name and ingredients of item
typedef struct
{
    char *itemName; 
    char *ingredients;
}
database;
database Mcdonalds[5];
void menu()
{
    //Defines Databse Item Names
    Mcdonalds[0].itemName = "Baked Apple Pie";
    Mcdonalds[1].itemName = "Snack Wrap";
    Mcdonalds[2].itemName = "McNuggets";
    Mcdonalds[3].itemName = "Big Mac";
    Mcdonalds[4].itemName = "French Fries";
    //Defines Databases ingredients 
    Mcdonalds[0].ingredients = ["Apples (Apples, Ascorbic Acid, Salt, Citric Acid)", 
    "Enriched Flour (Bleached Wheat Flour", "Niacin", "Reduced Iron", "Thiamine Mononitrate", "Riboflavin", "Folic Acid", 
    "Sugar", "Palm Oil", "Water", "Apple Juice Concentrate", "Modified Food Starch", "Invert Syrup", "Contains 2% or Less: Yeast, Salt, Cinnamon", 
    "Sunflower Lecithin", "L-cysteine (Dough Conditioner)", "Yeast Extract, Enzyme", "Beta-carotene (Color)"];

    Mcdonalds[1].ingredients = ["Boneless chicken breast meat", "water", "lemon juice concentrate", 
    "rice starch", "salt", "natural flavours (chicken, honey and plant source)", "vinegar", 
    "onion powder", "chicken broth powder", "garlic powder", "rice hull concentrate", "spices", 
    "sunflower oil", "vegetable oil", "mushroom juice concentrate", "spice extractives", "onion juice concentrate",
    "garlic juice concentrate", "herbs", "tumeric extractives (for colour)", "cooked on a grill", "lightly seasoned", 
    "butter"];

    Mcdonalds[2].ingredients = ["Boneless skinless chicken breast meat", "water", "vegetable oil shortening", 
    "wheat flour", "yellow corn flour", "modified corn starch", "rice starch", "salt", "baking powder", 
    "seasoning [wheat starch, yeast extract, salt, natural flavour (vegetable source)]", "spices", 
    "canola oil", "sodium aluminum phosphate", "dextrose", "wheat starch", "corn starch","vegetable oil", "canola oil"  
    "corn oil", "soybean oil", "soybean oil", "citric acid", "dimethylpolysiloxane";];

    Mcdonalds[3].ingredients = ["enriched wheat flour", "water", "sugar", "yeast", "vegetable oil (canola and/or soy)", 
    "vegetable protein (pea, potato, faba bean)", "sunflower oil", "corn dextrose", "corn starch", "corn maltodextrin", 
    "sesame seeds", "salt", "wheat", "gluten", "potato starch", "corn maltodextrin", "corn starch", "vinegar";];

    Mcdonalds[4].ingredients = ["Potatoes", "Vegetable Oil (canola Oil", "Corn Oil", "Soybean Oil", 
    "Hydrogenated Soybean Oil", "Natural Beef Flavor", "Dextrose, Sodium Acid Pyrophosphate", 
    "Salt", "Hydrogenated Milk";];
}
```

Comment: You cannot declare arrays like `char* a; a = ["x", "y"];` in C. Some other method have to be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is to

- assign a fixed size to the `ingredients` array
- initialize the database when you declare it

Something like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    char *itemName;
    char *ingredients[10];
}
database;

database Mcdonalds[] =
{
    {"pie" , {"apples" , "dough"}},
    {"wrap", {"chicken", "rice" }}
};
```

To get a little closer to what you have

- declare `ingredients` as a pointer-to-a-pointer
- create a `static` list of ingredients for each item
- assign the ingredients list to the appropriate struct

This is a little more work, but eliminates the need for a fixed-size array inside the `struct`.

```
typedef struct
{
    char *itemName;
    char **ingredients;
}
database;

database Mcdonalds[2];

void menu(void)
{
    static char *pieIngredients[]  = {"apples" , "dough", NULL};
    static char *wrapIngredients[] = {"chicken", "rice", "butter" , NULL};

    Mcdonalds[0].itemName = "pie";
    Mcdonalds[1].itemName = "wrap";
    Mcdonalds[0].ingredients = pieIngredients;
    Mcdonalds[1].ingredients = wrapIngredients;
}

int main(void)
{
    menu();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("Item '%s' contains\n", Mcdonalds[i].itemName);
        for (char **contains = Mcdonalds[i].ingredients; *contains != NULL; contains++)
            printf("   %s\n", *contains);
    }
}
```